# Is it possible to link or sync an excel spreadsheet with a PDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pdf, sync

I'm wondering if possible to link or sync an excel spreadsheet and a PDF, such that when the user updates the data in excel, a synced PDF version will automatically update?

Comment: If it is, it's probably not going to be a portable solution as embedding something like this usually requires some pretty specific connection. Usually you'd have some kind of build process or similar so that if you change the Excel file you'd build a new version of the PDF. If we assume [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html) applies it would mean you'd have to have Excel installed.

Answer (score 1):

To link do the following (assumption: you are using Adobe for PDFs):

1. Launch Adobe Acrobat, and then open the PDF file in which you want to insert a link that opens a file in Excel.
2. Scroll down to the point in the PDF document where you want to create a link to open the spreadsheet file in Excel. Click “Tools,” then “Typewriter” on the menu bar. Position the cursor where you want to insert text that describes the Excel file or informs viewer to click and open it.
3. Type “Click the Paper-Clip Icon Below to Open the Spreadsheet in Excel” or something similar. Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key after you finish entering the text.
4. Click “Tools” on the menu bar. Click “Comments & Markup,” and then click “Attach File as a Comment.” The Acrobat cursor changes to a push-pin icon. Click just below the text you entered with the Typewriter tool. A new window file browser appears.
5. Browse to the folder that contains the file you want a viewer to open in Excel. Highlight the spreadsheet filename, and then click “Select.” The File Attachment Properties window opens.
6. Click and select the paperclip icon option in the list, and then click “OK.” A paperclip icon appears below the text you entered earlier with the Typewriter tool.
7. Click and hold the paperclip icon. Drag it to the position below the text where you want it to display.
8. Click the floppy disk icon on the Acrobat toolbar to save the changes to the PDF. Alternatively, click “File” on the menu bar, and then click “Save.” Close Adobe Acrobat.
9. Open the edited PDF file with Adobe Acrobat reader. Scroll down to the new text in the file, and then click the paperclip icon. The attached spreadsheet opens in Excel. If the viewer does not have Excel installed on his computer, the file will open in another application that supports the file format in which you save the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I don't think this is going to give me what I'm looking for. If I'm not mistaken (and I probably am) you are embedding a link to an excel file in a PDF. I'm looking to create a PDF that when a corresponding excel file is edited, the PDF will show the same edits. For example, I am looking for something similar in functionality to the way docFlow links an InDesign file to a google doc, or the way in which an InDesign file can be synced with InCopy. Two way syncing would be great, but I'd settle for changes saved in excel also changed in PDF.